# Soap client using xsd and xml Spring boot

Tags: xml, spring-boot, soap, xsd, wsdl

I need to make a service to interact with the API server. I was provided with xsd and xml with a description of all the operations. But they do not have wsdl. Is it possible to make a web service without wsdl? Is it possible to somehow generate java classes on xsd and xml?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a soap service, and you want to consume it,  you can append `?wsdl` to the url to get the wsdl file.

If you want to expose a soap endpoint, you need to create your own wsdl file.

If you are using Maven, you can create java classes from the XSD schema file using the `jaxb2-maven-plugin`